# Searching in shortcode contents

Tags: shortcode, search, google-search

Can WP search be extended to search in shortcode generated contents?

If it is not a possibility please guide if replacing default WP search with Google Custom Search will solve the problem of searching through shortcode contents. Apparently, it should be possible because search engines index final html pages.

Answer (score 1):

It can be extended but not easily as the search searches just in the DB and shortcodes usually do some calculations in order to produce the final HTML.

To use the Google Custom Search you just need to get the code and add it to the site as a widget or part of the theme's code.